# C# - Tesseract OCR: scan multiple language at once

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

Any idea about how to do it?

```
TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default);
```

Usually, for one language, just adding the abbreviation is enough. But how if I want to scan an image with multiple languages in it? Btw, I use the package by Charles Weld. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try `IronOCR` and follow this guide: https://dev.to/mhamzap10/how-to-use-tesseract-ocr-in-c-9gc

Comment: Well, I've tried that one already, but I just want to try this tesseract one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to here](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues/79), the `+` syntax is supported, so you just need to add a `+` sign like the following:

```
TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "jpn+eng", EngineMode.Default); // jpn+eng for Japanese and English
```

Also, [according to here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Command-Line-Usage.html#simplest-invocation-to-ocr-an-image):

> The output can be different based on the order of languages, so -l
> eng+hin can give different result than -l hin+eng.

From what I can see, the language you specify first has better accuracy.

Comment: Btw, for the second thing you mentioned (The output can be different based on the order of languages, so -l eng+hin can give different result than -l hin+eng), how can I use it?

Comment: @Riiko: `how can I use it?`. I'm not sure what you are asking. In my example, `"jpn+eng"` can give different results than `"eng+jpn"`. In other words, order matters. The documentation I quoted is from the command-line documentation.

Comment: I see, then I don't need that. The first one works just fine, and I'm not using the command stuff.